How to make zsh's ssh autocompletion complete "Host" instead of "Hostname"
With the following entry in ~/.ssh/config:
Host server
    Hostname server.example.com
    Port 1234

ssh s<tab> doesn't complete server, but completes server.example.com. How can I make it complete server?
I'm on Fedora with zsh 5.9.
Additional context: It appears that on Debian Bookworm (also zsh 5.9) this doesn't happen.

It seems to be defined in /usr/share/zsh/...functions/_ssh_hosts. From what I understand it's using both server and server.example.com for the completion.

@Fravadona Hmm, I double checked on Debian, it goes the other way (only Host, no Hostname in completion)...

Did you check the source code? I'm not on debian by I checked on RedHat and macOS and there's a case with the glob ((#i)host(|name)) that should match Host AND Hostname

@Fravadona the case is there. It seems like Debian's zsh auto completion doesn't use _ssh_hosts at all. While on Fedora, after I touched _ssh_hosts, both Host and hostname start to show up in completion.

Actually I don't know what's going on now. I tried another Fedora machine, and touch didn't change anything. I guess something happened on my first Fedora machine after I did touch. All of them have the same zshrc configuration, and same if I start zsh with no configuration and only enable autocompletion.

On my Fedora, I found IPREFIX is always empty when _ssh_hosts starts, and it returns in the first else branch at the top of the file. If I remove the && return in the else branch, both Host and Hostname show up in completion result.

I found a fix, the difference between the systems are likely caused by how zsh handles the hosts tag. I added my answer to a duplication question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/788427/38242
